# XAML gradients collection

Tags: silverlight, xaml, gradient

I try to give my custom control a beautiful backround. But I'm not a designer, I can not create a nice gradient. I searched the internet but found nothing. Maybe you know some sites with collections of beautiful gradients, writing in XAML?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

try [silverlightxap.com](http://www.silverlightxap.com/controls/53/expander-style) , there are few control samples with gradients